# what is " >>= " operator?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, operators

What is the meaning of `>>=` operator?

Sample code:

```
int rangeBitCount(int a, int b) {

  int ans = 0;
  for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
    int t = i;
    while (t != 0) {
      ans += t & 1;
      t >>= 1;
    }
  }

  return ans;
}
```

Comment: [Right shift assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Right_shift_assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **[Right shift assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Right_shift_assignment)** operator.

The right shift assignment operator moves the specified amount of bits to the right and assigns the result to the variable. See the right shift operator for more details.

> Syntax
>
> Operator: x >>= y
> Meaning:  x   = x >> y

In you case `t >>= 1;` is equivalent to `t = t >> 1;`. This means that the value of t will be shifted 1 bit to right.